# Get the URL of a mp3 file in google drive so it is playable with Twilio's twiml

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, twilio-twiml

Does anyone know how to get the correct type of Url of a audio file stored in google drive, so I can use it in a `<Play>` tag in Twilio's Twiml.

I'm trying ti initiate a call from Google apps script.

Everything works, the call even comes through. But when you answer the call it says "sorry an application error has occured".

I'm assuming something is wrong with the url, because I tested it with a `<Say>` tag and it worked. I set the sharing option so anyone can have access, so that's not the issue.

any help is welcome.

```
  var payload = {
    "To": fullNumber,
    "From" : "+17777777777",
    "Twiml" : "<Response><Play>https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/view</Play></Response>",
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of googling I figured it out.

you have to change the `&` to `&amp;` in the url that google gives you.

the best way for me was to hard code the beginning of the url and then just get the file id through a simple `var id = file.getId();` then I add it to the first half of the url which is a always the same like this.

`"Twiml" : "<Response><Play>https://docs.google.com/uc?export=play&amp;id=" + id + "</Play></Response>",`